# How to build only approved pull requests using the multi-branch plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, multibranch-pipeline

I use the [multibranch plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-multibranch) to scan new pull requests, and I need to limit my builds to approved pull requests only. I filter the approved pull requests after they are scanned, however the repository scanner can only tell whether a pull request has new commits.

I tried the the [PR comment build plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-pr-comment-build) and added the `Trigger build on pull request review` property to the github branch source to no avail - it seems that adding this property doesn't have any effect on how the scanner processes pull requests.

Can I tell the repository scanner to trigger a build on new reviews? Is there any other way to build pull requests only after approval?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to accept that there was no way to make the branch scan consider non-git objects (such as github reviews).

I ended up making a pipeline that kept a list of all the yet-to-be-approved pull requests (using the github API), and once a pull request was approved it would trigger a build on it.

It feels hacky, but unfortunately that was the only way I could think of to build only on approval...
Important note: this solution requires an existing multibranch job to work with.
So this is what I did:

First query for the existing pull requests and their status (install the [httpRequest](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request) plugin):

```groovy
// Send a query to github and get the response JSON
def githubQuery(Map args = [:]) {
  def formattedQuery = args.query.replaceAll('\n', ' ').replaceAll('"', '\\\\"')
  def response = httpRequest(
    authentication: args.auth,
    httpMode: 'POST',
    requestBody: """{ "query": "${formattedQuery}" }""",
    url: "https://api.github.com/graphql"
  )
  (response.status == 200) ? readJSON(text: response.content) : [:]
}

def getPRStatus(Map args = [:]) {
  // Build the query to get all open pull requests and their status
  def query = """query {
    organization(login: "${args.organization}") {
      repositories(first: 30) {
        nodes {
          name
          pullRequests(first: 100, states: [OPEN]) {
            nodes {
              number
              state
              reviews(first: 10, states: [APPROVED]) {
                totalCount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }"""
  def response = githubQuery(args + [query: query])
  def repositories = response?.data.organization.repositories.nodes
  // Organize the pull requests into approved and unapproved groups
  repositories?.collectEntries { repo ->
    // Take out draft pull requests
    def prs = repo.pullRequests.nodes.findAll { it.state != "DRAFT" }
    def repoPrs = [
      unapproved: prs.findAll { it.reviews.totalCount == 0 },
      approved: prs.findAll { it.reviews.totalCount > 0 }
    ].collectEntries { category, categoryPrs ->
      [ category, categoryPrs.collect { it.number } ]
    }
    [ repo.name, repoPrs ]
  }
}
```

Then compare each pull request's status to its status from the previous poll, and build only those that changed their status to approved:

```groovy
def monitorRecentlyApprovedPRs(Map args = [:]) {
  def prMap = getPRStatus(args)
  // Build recently approved pull requests on each repository
  prMap.each { repoName, repoPrs ->
    // Get previously unapproved pull requests
    def previouslyUnapproved = currentBuild.previousBuild?.buildVariables?."${repoName}"?.tokenize(",").collect { it.toInteger() } ?: []
    // Build recently approved pull requests
    repoPrs.approved.intersect(previouslyUnapproved).each { prNumber ->
      build job: "/${args.multibranch}/PR-${prNumber}", wait: false
    }
    env."${repoName}" = repoPrs.unapproved.join(",")
  }
}
```

When calling `monitorRecentlyApprovedPRs` you'll have to provide these arguments:

```groovy
monitorRecentlyApprovedPRs organization: "YOUR-ORGANIZATION", auth: "GITHUB-CREDENTIALS", multibranch: "PATH-TO-THE-MULTIBRANCH-JOB-IN-JENKINS"
```

Finally, update the multibranch's `Jenkinsfile` to skip unapproved PRs:

```groovy
def shouldBuildPR(Map args = [:]) {
  // Get pull request info
  def query = """query {
    organization(login: "${args.organization}") {
      repository(name: "${args.repo}") {
        pullRequest(number: ${args.pr}) {
          state
          reviews(first: 10, states: [APPROVED]) {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }"""
  def response = githubQuery(args + [query: query])
  def prInfo = response?.data.organization.repository.pullRequest
  def shouldBuild = (
    // Skip merged pull requests
    prInfo.state != "MERGED" &&
    // Check for draft state
    (prInfo.state != "DRAFT") &&
    // Check for approval
    (prInfo.reviews.totalCount > 0)
  )
  shouldBuild
}
```

To call `shouldBuildPR` you'll provide these arguments:

```groovy
shouldBuildPR(organization: "YOUR-ORGANIZATION", repo: "PR-REPO", auth: "GITHUB-CREDENTIALS", pr: env.CHANGE_ID)
```

If the returned value is `false` you should stop the rest of the pipeline's execution. Things would have been a lot simpler if the multibranch pipeline plugin provided a PR status environment variable :)

Comment: can you post the steps you took to trigger this build please?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the steps to control PR builds according to their status. I hope it's a least somewhat useful, as it multiples the amount of github API calls...